# What are these five petal pink flowers?

Tags: identification

Bees love these pink flowers. I would like more of them next year - but I need to find out the name of the plant. Can you help me?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Saponaria, probably S. ocymoides; commonly known as Soapwort. Compare the petal shape and flower form (lots of photos at this site):

http://luirig.altervista.org/flora/taxa/index2.php?scientific-name=saponaria+ocymoides

Comment: I was thinking Phlox until I zoomed in to see the calyxes and I do believe you are right on the money honey!  Good job Jurp...

Answer (score 0):

This not a soapwort or a phlox. It is a silene armeria.
Sweet William flycatch-common name

Comment: Possibly, but difficult to tell with the photos. To be certain, we need to see the anthers (blue in Saponaria) and a very clear picture of the petals (notched in Silene, not in Saponaria). The calyx, as pictured, is much more suggestive of Saponaria than Silene (Silene calyces are not as elongated).